# apache poi ppt to png emf

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I would like to ask about library APACHE POI. I have a .pptx file and with the example which I found on internet I split each slide into separate images. This works great when slide containts .png, .jpeg images but as soon as I have .emf files in slide this image disappear. So I want to have the same copy of slide but with .emf file as well. Is this possible?

version: Apache POI 3.12

Thanks a lot

Comment: Upgrade to the most recent version of Apache POI and try again?

Comment: I did it but i suppose its not supported this feature

Comment: EMF is currently not supported out-of-the-box.

You need to provide your own ImageRenderer with the help of the FreeHep library.

see for an [example of how to use FreeHep](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/ImageRender-for-EMF-convert-PPTX-slides-include-EMF-images-into-PNG-td5717773.html) and on [how to provide your own ImageRenderer](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/sl/draw/ImageRenderer.java?view=markup)

I might :) try to come up with an detailed answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, EMF is not supported out of the box ... and as [FreeHep](http://java.freehep.org/) decided to have a [LGPL license](http://java.freehep.org/license.html) it's unlikely that we will [include in our release](https://www.apache.org/legal/resolved#category-x).

In POI you basically have two options to provide a custom image renderer:

- implement and register your [ImageRenderer](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/sl/draw/ImageRenderer.java?view=markup) implementation in the Graphics2D context via `setRenderingHint(Drawable.IMAGE_RENDERER, new MyImageRendener())`. The drawback is, that it will be called for any images and you loose the default handling for bitmap/wmf images
- or provide a custom [DrawFactory](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/sl/draw/DrawFactory.java?view=markup) which serves your own [DrawPictureShape](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/sl/draw/DrawPictureShape.java?view=markup) implementation - as in the example below - which only diverts to the EMF renderer when necessary
  (*looking at this example, the current POI ImageRenderer handling doesn't look flexible and instead of having a global handler, it might be better to register a handler per content-type ...*)

Apart of the [usual POI component](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) I've included [freehep-graphics2d](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/freehep/freehep-graphics2d/2.4/), [freehep-graphicsbase](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/freehep/freehep-graphicsbase/2.4/), [freehep-graphicsio](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/freehep/freehep-graphicsio/2.4/), [freehep-graphicsio-emf](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/freehep/freehep-graphicsio-emf/2.4/) and [freehep-io](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/freehep/freehep-io/2.2.2/).

The example is far from being finished, but I guess you get at least a kick-start:

```
package org.apache.poi.xslf;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawFactory;
import org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawPictureShape;
import org.apache.poi.sl.draw.Drawable;
import org.apache.poi.sl.draw.ImageRenderer;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.PictureData;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.PictureData.PictureType;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.PictureShape;
import org.apache.poi.util.POILogFactory;
import org.apache.poi.util.POILogger;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureShape;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;
import org.freehep.graphicsio.emf.EMFInputStream;
import org.freehep.graphicsio.emf.EMFRenderer;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestEMFRender {
    private final static POILogger LOG = POILogFactory.getLogger(TestEMFRender.class);

    @Test
    public void render() throws Exception {
        XMLSlideShow ppt = getDummy();

        Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)pgsize.getWidth(), (int)pgsize.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D graphics = initGraphicsCtx(img);

        // draw stuff
        ppt.getSlides().get(0).draw(graphics);

        // save the result
        File outfile = new File("bla.png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", outfile);

        // cleanup
        graphics.dispose();
        img.flush();
        ppt.close();
    }

    static XMLSlideShow getDummy() throws IOException {
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("kiwilogo.emf");
        PictureData pd = ppt.addPicture(fis, PictureType.EMF);
        fis.close();
        XSLFSlide sl = ppt.createSlide();
        XSLFPictureShape ps = sl.createPicture(pd);
        ps.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 100, 100));
        return ppt;
    }

    static Graphics2D initGraphicsCtx(BufferedImage img) {
        Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
        // default rendering options
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);

        // custom draw factory
        DrawFactory df = new DrawFactory(){
            public DrawPictureShape getDrawable(PictureShape<?,?> shape) {
                return new DrawPictureShapeEmf(shape);
            }
        };
        graphics.setRenderingHint(Drawable.DRAW_FACTORY, df);

        df.fixFonts(graphics);

        return graphics;
    }

    static class DrawPictureShapeEmf extends DrawPictureShape {
        public DrawPictureShapeEmf(PictureShape<?,?> shape) {
            super(shape);
        }


        @Override
        public void drawContent(Graphics2D graphics) {
            PictureData data = getShape().getPictureData();
            if(data == null) return;

            Rectangle2D anchor = getAnchor(graphics, getShape());
            Insets insets = getShape().getClipping();

            try {
                String contentType = data.getContentType();
                ImageRenderer renderer =
                    PictureType.EMF.contentType.equals(contentType)
                    ? new ImgRenderer()
                    : super.getImageRenderer(graphics, contentType);

                renderer.loadImage(data.getData(), data.getContentType());
                renderer.drawImage(graphics, anchor, insets);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.log(POILogger.ERROR, "image can't be loaded/rendered.", e);
            }
        }

    }


    static class ImgRenderer implements ImageRenderer {
        EMFRenderer emfRenderer;

        public void loadImage(InputStream data, String contentType) throws IOException {
            emfRenderer = new EMFRenderer(new EMFInputStream(data));
        }

        public void loadImage(byte[] data, String contentType) throws IOException {
            loadImage(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), contentType);
        }

        public Dimension getDimension() {
            return emfRenderer.getSize();
        }

        public void setAlpha(double alpha) {
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage() {
            return null;
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage(Dimension dim) {
            return null;
        }

        public boolean drawImage(Graphics2D ctx, Rectangle2D graphicsBounds) {
            return drawImage(ctx, graphicsBounds, null);
        }

        public boolean drawImage(Graphics2D ctx, Rectangle2D graphicsBounds, Insets clip) {
            AffineTransform at = ctx.getTransform();
            try {
                Dimension emfDim = emfRenderer.getSize();
                // scale output bounds to image bounds
                ctx.translate(graphicsBounds.getX(), graphicsBounds.getY());
                ctx.scale(graphicsBounds.getWidth()/emfDim.getWidth(), graphicsBounds.getHeight()/emfDim.getHeight());

                // TODO: handle clipping

                emfRenderer.paint(ctx);

                return true;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // TODO: logging
                return false;
            } finally {
                ctx.setTransform(at);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but is possible this solution? With function ppt.getPictureData() I got all pictures in presentation and than I find only picture which ha .emf extension. I convert it to svg with freehep and than from svg to jpg, but now I need to replace old .emf  with new .jpg with function picture.setData(newImageStream) but I'm not sure if this will work

Comment: So in your new issue you want to replace emf images with jpg, right? So simply adapt my approach to get JPGs from FreeHeps EMFRenderer and change the byte AND the content-type - I guess you have to iterate through all the slides and change the references there too.
If this is what you want, then open a new question and I might adopt the code to it ...

Comment: Yes I got it now :) ... But the problem in version apache po 3.15 is, that after this conversion is not working conversion from ppt -> images in images are still missing files, but with version 3.13 is working everyting OK :) .. So thanks for your time :)

Comment: As I maintain the POI SL rendering stuff, I'm picky about "is not working" quotes. EMF rendering never worked. I've put a lot of effort in to provide common SL rendering in 3.14, and the API has changed in this context too. I've ran the above code in the POI 3.16 trunk, so with this, EMF rendering works. When I've tested, I've noticed that FreeHep can't process our example wrench.emf and failed with an EOFException. So maybe your embedded EMFs also have that problem.

Comment: Yes maybe, but the same code is working great with 3.13 and with 3.15 not. So nevermind . Exactly the same ppt presentation and same code is working on 3.13 and with 3.15 images disappear with 3.15. But nevermind I solved it so thanks :)